# Elegant chained 'or's for tests on same variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What's the sensible way of saying this.

```
if @thing == "01" or "02" or "03" or "04" or "05"
```

(The numbers are contained in a column of datatype string.)

Comment: The correct, but verbose version would be `if @thing == "01" || @thing == "02" || ...`

Comment: Please note that [`and`/`or` is *not* the same as `&&`/`||` in Ruby](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make an array and use `.include?`

```
if ["01","02","03","04","05"].include?(@thing)
```

If the values really are all consecutive, you can use a range like `(1..5).include?`  For strings, you can use:

```
if ("01".."05").include?(@thing)
```

Comment: Or in this particular case, `("01".."05").include?(@thing)`

Comment: If only Ruby arrays had binary search, this could take `O(log n)` time instead of `O(n)` time.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: Ruby has sets, so `Set.new("01".."05").include?` would be `O(1)`.

Comment: @NiklasB. Added.  I was testing to make sure it actually worked when your comment came in :)

Comment: @crymer: Nobody said it would (except for Matthew, which was a different answer).

Comment: @Niklas: look at the answer Michael posted, "If the values really are all consecutive, you can use a range like `[01-05].include?`"

Comment: @crymer11 Maybe an early typo? fixed several minutes ago. Refresh your page

Comment: @Michael Yeah, I now see it's been fixed.

Comment: @crymer: That was Matthew's answer.

Comment: These are all great responses, thanks so much. I went with "if ("01".."05").include?(@thing)" in this particular case.

Comment: @NiklasB. Why doesn't it work as expected in that case? `('01'..'10').to_a` gives back what I would expect.

Comment: @Andrew: Strange. I could have sworn that it created a range with letters in it last time I looked, but I must have been dreaming. Now I wonder *why* it works. It must be treating numeric strings specially when lexicographically generating the range... This surprises me a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Or use a case statement:

```
case @thing
when "01", "02", "03", "04", "05"
  # do your things
end
```

Two variations of this approach:

```
case @thing
when "01".."05"
  # do your things
end

case @thing
when *%w[01 02 03 04 05]
  # do your things
end
```

Because `case` uses `===`, you could also write: `("01".."05") === @thing`

Comment: Nice, didn't know that you could use the splat operator in `when` branches.

Comment: The `===` operator is misleading, IMHO, as it means something completely different in other languages where it's available. `include?` is much more readable.

Comment: I agree with you, I've never used it in that way ;)