# Are there shorter ways to perform checks on the same variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Elegant chained 'or's for tests on same variable in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260050/elegant-chained-ors-for-tests-on-same-variable-in-ruby)

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to know if there are *shorter* ways to perform same checks as in the following:

```
if (variable == 'A') or (variable == 'B')
  ...
end

if (variable == 'A') or (variable == 'B') or ... or (variable == 'Z')
  ...
end
```

Note that I have to repeat statements related to the `variable ==` "part" more than once and one time for each check. I would not repeat that "part" and make things shorter. *Is it possible in Ruby/Ruby on Rails? If so, how can I make that?*

Comment: Please note that [`and`/`or` is *not* the same as `&&`/`||` in Ruby](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
if %w[A B C].include? variable
```

or if you have an actual range of values:

```
if ('A'..'Z').include? variable
```