# Shorter way to say "anwer="this" or answer = "that"

Tags: ruby, function, expression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Elegant chained 'or’s for tests on same variable in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260050/elegant-chained-ors-for-tests-on-same-variable-in-ruby)

`answer="this" or answer = "that"` is wordy

I would like to be able use an expression more like `answer =("this" or that")` but I know I can't use that expression as the `or` gets done and then the (true or false) result is compared to answer, so that is not what I want.  Something more like  a =~ [a/c] but I need interpolation.

Comment: Oops - I misread `answer = "this"` as though it had been `answer == "this"` Previous comments deleted. (unless you really mean equality `==` rather than assignment `=`)

Comment: In case you did actually mean equality `==` here's my earlier comment restored:  `["this","that","the other"].include? answer`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260050/elegant-chained-ors-for-tests-on-same-variable-in-ruby/10260062#10260062

Comment: testing for answer = "this" will always be true I believe since it'll assign "this" to `answer` and test existence of answer, which is true

Comment: Can you please revisit your question and give a better explanation of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I smell premature optimization and yack shaving.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you mean `==` (equality comparison) rather than `=` (assignment). If that's the case, depending on the situation, you can do one of the following:

```
if [this, that].include? answer

# or #

case answer
when this, that
  # do something
end
```

The latter is better for when you have many sets of options that you want to check for, while the former is more readable when you just have one set of options that you're interested in. (I'll usually stick the options in a named variable, so it would be something more like `if right_answers.include? answer`. That way it reads clearly and is easy to maintain.)

Comment: +1 for the case statement. I think that's what @junky really wants.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use a regex:

```
answer = 'this'
true if answer =~ /th[is|at]/
=> true

answer = 'that'
true if answer =~ /th[is|at]/
=> true

answer = 'blah'
true if answer =~ /th[is|at]/
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `this || that` does not actually return TRUE or FALSE.  It will return the first item, unless the item is 'falsey' (false or nil, note that "" is not false nor nil), otherwise it will return the second item.  Therefore the following will work:

```
foo = nil
bar = "that"
baz = ""
qux = false

answer = foo || bar # => "that"
answer = bar || foo # => "that"
answer = baz || bar # => ""
answer = foo || qux # => false
answer = qux || foo # => nil
```

So, in reality, your expression `answer =("this" or that")` will actually work, except that it will always evaluate to "this", since "this" is not 'falsey'.

Comment: As a matter of preference, I typically use `||` rather than `or`, since it behaves more predictably in terms of order of precedence.